# Problem Installing Skype libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5)

Tags: apt, dependencies, skype

I tried to install skype from terminal. (i'm newbie on ubuntu)

- First: wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
- Second: sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
- Finally:  sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb

but i get an error that says

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> skypeforlinux : Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**and I am using Ubuntu 16 LTS.**

How to solve this? or how to install the required dependency ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: okay, but could you help me with the current problem? @user535733

Comment: yes i know, i just thought there is an easier work around solution. @user535733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try install with snap?

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install skype --classic
```